# Tree material angular 2 selected state

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a Angular 2 Material Tree when I click a node from the tree I need to have the selected state on that node to change the background color.
I have no idea how I can do that. I didn't find nothing in documentation to help me. Here is the html code and a picture that how it should look the tree

[image: That is how it should look the tree when clicking on a node]

```
       <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" #matTree [ngStyle]="{ 'color': red}">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
          <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
          {{node.filename}}
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding >
          <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" click="onClick()">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{node.filename}}
        </mat-tree-node>
      </mat-tree>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to develop a working example of what you are trying to achieve. The presentation is basic but it uses a layout identical to your example code. I included a link at the very bottom to my solution. It basically boils down to the below code.

#### component.ts

```
  // inside of the component class

  @ViewChildren(MatTreeNode, { read: ElementRef }) treeNodes: ElementRef[];

  hasListener: any[] = [];
  oldHighlight: ElementRef;

  updateHighlight = (newHighlight: ElementRef) => {
    this.oldHighlight && this.renderer.removeClass(this.oldHighlight.nativeElement, 'background-highlight');

    this.renderer.addClass(newHighlight.nativeElement, 'background-highlight');
    this.oldHighlight = newHighlight;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.treeNodes.forEach((reference) => {
      if (!this.hasListener.includes(reference.nativeElement)) {
        console.log('* tick');

        this.renderer.listen(reference.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
          this.updateHighlight(reference);
        });
        this.renderer.listen(reference.nativeElement.children.item(0), 'click', () => {
          this.updateHighlight(reference);
        });

        this.hasListener = this.hasListener.concat([ reference.nativeElement ]);
      }
    });

    this.hasListener = this.hasListener.filter((element) => document.contains(element));
    console.log('*', this.hasListener.length);
  }
```

#### component.css

```
.background-highlight {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

I positioned most of my logic inside of the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. This is so I could access the results of the `@ViewChild` query. The query returns references to all of the `<mat-tree-node></mat-tree-node>` elements in the template. The results are stored in `this.treeNodes` as a QueryList.

I iterate across the list. I check to see if the referenced `nativeElement` already has its event listeners. The event listeners trigger on mouse `click`. The callback `updateHighlight` handles the removal and addition of the `background-highlight` css class so that it remains unique in the DOM.

I added two event listeners targeting the `<mat-tree-node></mat-tree-node>` and its nested `<button></button>` element. Clicking both places highlights the tree node all the same.

In `updateHighlight` I remove the `background-highlight` class from wherever it was previously added (if applicable). Whatever is currently clicked gets the `background-highlight` class. A reference to the clicked element replaces the previous value of `this.oldHighlight`.

For the sake of performance, I included `this.hasListener`. The array stores the `<mat-tree-node></mat-tree-node>` elements that have already received their listeners. I can check the array to ensure that I am not needlessly overwriting listeners with each pass of `ngAfterViewChecked`.

The last bit of logic keeps `this.hasListener` from growing out of control. Any elements no longer attached to the DOM are no longer a concern.

I kept in two `console.log` statements because their outputs reflect that the code works beyond highlighting clicked tree nodes.

For any other questions, see the repository: https://github.com/sosmaniac-FCC/mat-tree-node-example/tree/master/src/app/components/example-one . I did import some extra utilities from `@angular/core`.

Of course, if I missed the mark anywhere just let me know. I will follow-up the best I can.

Answer (score 27):

There's an easier cleaner way to do this.

All you have to do is add
`(click)="activeNode = node" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight': activeNode === node }"`
to each `mat-tree-node`.

Don't forget to add the `activeNode` variable to your component.

That's it!

Comment: [NIce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exhejg-i9plj1?file=app/tree-dynamic-example.css) BTW - do you know - if it's possible to add [branch lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202100/angular-material-add-branch-lines-for-tree) ? .

Comment: Never tried it, but a quick search gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202100/angular-material-add-branch-lines-for-tree)

Comment: Don't forget the CSS changes for the component as mentioned above in the response from @John

`.background-highlight {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have this method

[image]

But it only serves me to detect the last selected element. If I want to know where this element comes from, that is, in this case, what month and year is the selected fortnight, I don't know how to do it

Thanks