# How to apply styles for tree component of angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using tree component of angular material for my project.Here is   [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9d7cvk) link,Here i need to achieve two things:

1)The text color of the child element has to change on mouse hover.

2)On clicking/selecting the child element the background color has to be changed,The background color as to be constant until i select the next child element something like list with **selection**.

Something like this

[image]

Comment: [Documentation ?](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles)

Comment: for your 2nd question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632569/tree-material-angular-2-selected-state/50636110) in here you can find how to change the background color of the selected state

Comment: Ya tried this example,it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i have created [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9d7cvk-juhceh?file=app/tree-loadmore-example.css) demo

this code work as per your requirement

i have added some in

`tree-loadmore-example.html`

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding
  (click)="activeNode = node" [ngClass]="{ 'background-highlight': activeNode === node }">
        <button mat-icon-button></button> <span class="txtColor">{{node.item}}</span>
</mat-tree-node>
```

and in **.ts** added

```
activeNode:any;
```

Comment: you are awesome, Thank you very much.