# Angular material - Add branch lines for tree?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I've created a simple tree with [Angular material tree](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exhejg-vx5i7c?file=app/tree-dynamic-example.html

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" >
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding   >
    <button mat-icon-button ></button>
    {{node.item}}
  </mat-tree-node>


  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding   >
    <button mat-icon-button 
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.item + '2'}}
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="node.isLoading"
                      mode="indeterminate"
                      class="example-tree-progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-tree-node>


</mat-tree>
```

It looks like :

[image]

But how can I add branch lines ? something like (from [here](https://tina-material-tree.firebaseapp.com/simple-tree)):

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no such functionality out of the box. But you can apply it via CSS.
There is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested)

Comment: Shame, but no. Found it at stackblitz.com. In that example nested material tree is used, but It is easy to apply for material tree.

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]    I am using mat-nested-tree.
step-1 Add a left border to both the li.
step-2 Add another div inside li.
apply below css
see image...

```
.setBorder{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 22px;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.borderMain{
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: reply to the above answer]
the line breaks when two nodes expanded under one parent node

Answer (score 1):

In reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52203131/14783892, change this:

```
.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -41px;
}
```

To this:

```
.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child > li > ul {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-left: -41px;
}
```

This change should resolve the line-breaking issue.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for the line breaks when two nodes expanded under one parent node just clear your entire `.html`, `.ts`, `.css` or `.scss` files completely. Then paste the above code in the same way as there in stackblitz., just add:
`import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';`
in `.ts` file along with code it will work's well and fine now.